# TCP/IP and TCP and IP difference?

Tags: tcp, ip, protocols

Is there a difference between TCP/IP and [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol)?

I thought always TCP/IP is just TCP and IP together but it looks like TCP/IP is a family that has a lot more protocols, not just TCP and IP.

- IP: Internetprotocol
- TCP: Transmission control protocol
- TCP/IP: Main protocols are TCP and IP, but it includes a lot more.

Did I understand that correct, or is that wrong?

Comment: [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and the [Internet Protocol Suite, commonly known as TCP/IP, because they are the two most important core protocols in the suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following link you may distinguish the two models OSI and TCP/IP:
http://electronicdesign.com/what-s-difference-between/what-s-difference-between-osi-seven-layer-network-model-and-tcpip

In case of TCP/IP model, it supports other protocols in different layers than 4 and 3, but also TCP protocol could be replaced by UDP or STCP and it will still remain as TCP/IP model.

Answer (score 6):

When TCP and IP are mentioned separately then they mean a transport layer ([RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)) and a network layer protocol ([RFC 791](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791)) respectively. But when mentioned in TCP/IP format they mean a stack which TCP/IP suite.

Answer (score 4):

TCP/IP is a protocol stack which contains different protocols required for the data transfer from sender to receiver. In this the IP denotes the Layer 3 protocol which is connectionless and does not have error recovery procedure. So Layer 4 protocol comes into role to give reliability and help to recover the lost packet. UDP is also a protocol in this stack.

IP - Network Layer protocol for logical addressing.

TCP - Layer 4 protocol which ensures reliability and is connection oriented.